# ¿Hay frases en español que usen todas las letras de una vez?

Tags: gramática, vocabulario, ortografía

Hay frases en español que tengan todas las letras del alfabeto a la vez.  En inglés el término es [pangram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_quick_brown_fox_jumps_over_the_lazy_dog) y el ejemplo es

> The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dogs

Esta frase tiene todas las letras del alfabeto inglés incluido - aunque tenga la **O** cuatro veces.

¿Hay ejemplos de panagramas en español? Las ejemplos de Wikipedia todos tienen dificultad con **W** - usan las palabras **whisky** o de **kiwi**.

---

No voy discutir sobre la utilidad de las pangramas...

Pensé en este ejercicio cuando tuve que entregar una muestra de escritura con la mano que normalmente *no* escribo. Escogí el ejemplo inglés de arriba pero me puse a pensar si hay otro ejemplo en español y les dejo el rompecabeza aquí por si acaso.

En inglés normalmente se limite a una narracion solamente, en este sentido hay limite.

---

Pensándolo mas, todo esto tiene que ver con el vocabulario español que **incluye** las letras **W** y **K** en la lengua moderna.  Se observa (Wikipedia) que Don Quixote incluye 1.640.502 letras y solamente aparecen:

- **W** 2 veces
- **K** 0 veces

En Español moderna las frequéncias son **W** 1:10000 y **K** 2:10000.  Contanto letras así se hace en el campo de [Criptoanálisis](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Criptoan%C3%A1lisis)

---

Busqué por curiosidad las frecuencias de aparicion de las letras por medio de [Google N-Gram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=j%2C%C3%B1%2Cx%2Cw%2Ck&year_start=1860&year_end=2000&corpus=21&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cj%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C%C3%B1%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cx%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cw%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ck%3B%2Cc0) y aquí están.  Se nota un cambio de la orden en los ultimos 50 años.

[image]

Comment: no tendría objecciónes a palabras o uso regionales para la W o la K.  En Puerto Rico ya observo bastante...

Comment: Interesante pregunta (aunque off-topic), pero por lo que tú mismo explicas, estos panagramas sí existen en español. Dada una frase de longitud suficiente, no tendrías problemas en usar todas las letras del alfabeto, por supuesto. La dificultad podría estar en encontrar el más corto, o restringir al uso de cada letra una sola vez. Para la W, whisky o kiwi (o waterpolo, windsurf, wolframio, ...) son aceptadas en español, o podrías usar un topónimo o nombre propio (Washington, Wenceslao, Westafila)

Comment: Excelente trabajo.Lo encontré buscando la frase de Exhíbanse politiquillos zafios... una de las que utilizaba hace muchos años en las clases de mecanografía, para conseguir que los niños cogiesen velocidad escribiendo. La dificultad en las frases, al escribirlas muchas veces a máquina, más velocidad y destreza en este ejercicio. Muchas Gracias.

Comment: Recurso interesante: [pangram calculator/checker](https://planetcalc.com/6914/)

Answer (score 6):

¡Interesante! Alguna vez había jugado a usar todas las vocales en una palabra. Por ejemplo, "murciélago" lo cumple. Sin embargo, este juego no lo conocía.

Busqué y encontré una discusión en Wordreference al respecto. [Alguien menciona los siguientes](http://forum.wordreference.com/threads/una-sola-oraci%C3%B3n-que-tiene-todas-las-letras.328137/#post-1956499), que por cierto se hacen llamar **pangramas**:

> El veloz murciélago hindú comía feliz cardillo y kiwi. La cigüeña
>   tocaba el saxofón detrás del palenque de paja.
>
> El pingüino Wenceslao hizo kilómetros bajo exhaustiva lluvia y frío,
>   añoraba a su querido cachorro.
>
> Jovencillo emponzoñado de whisky, qué mala figurota exhibes.
>
> Exhíbanse politiquillos zafios, con orejas kilométricas y uñas de
>   gavilán.
>
> El jefe buscó el éxtasis en un imprevisto baño de whisky y gozó como
>   un duque.
>
> Joven emponzoñado con el whisky, qué fin te aguarda exhibir. (De un
>   relato policiaco de Esteban Padrós de Palcios, gracias [野原無](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/users/12422/%E9%87%8E%E5%8E%9F%E7%84%A1))

Comment: "Exhíbanse politiquillos zafios, con orejas kilométricas y uñas de gavilán." no usa W.

Comment: "El veloz murciélago hindú comía feliz cardillo y kiwi", esa es la frase de ejemplo que te ponen cuando estas eligiendo una fuente de texto XD

Comment: @Diego le podemos añadir _en Washington_ : )

Comment: "Arte bizco calizo, dejador eferente, flagrante guitarrero, histríonico impenetrable, jactancioso kriptónico lacerando morlacos; nadador obtuso parco, quid rey; si tan útil venal xocota, yacedor zalamero"                                                         Cada palabra empieza por una letra distinta del abecedario y además cada palabra tiene una longitud +1 o bien -1 que la precedente.

Comment: "Ay boj caco, débil espina fallida, gabinete habitable idealmente, jeroglífico kilográmetro lacónicamente multitudinario, negligentemente, omnipotentemente prestidigitador quincuagenario, representante substituible transmarino, ufanamente vaquerizo, xilófago yuntero zazoso"

Comment: @user55514, Interesante. Me encantan esos usos de "Kriptónico" y "xocota"

Comment: Observo que recibí un voto negativo. ¿Podría saber el por qué para así intentar mejorar la respuesta?

Comment: Una variación de la tercera, juega un papel clave en un relato policiaco de Esteban Padrós de Palcios: **"Joven emponzoñado con el whisky, qué fin te aguarda exhibir."**

Comment: @野原無 ¡qué buena esta! La añadí a la respuesta : )

Answer (score 1):

- El señor Gómez, un viejo saxofonista, pedía queso, cancha, kiwi y habas.
- El viejo saxofonista del ceño fruncido se sentó a la mesa y le pidió al mozo un sándwich de queso, un gajo de naranja, un kiwi y un cuarto de kilo de habas.

Comment: El viejo saxofonista del ceño fruncido se sentó a la mesa y le pidió al mozo un sándwich de queso, un gajo de naranja, un kiwi y un cuarto de kilo de habas.

Answer (score 1):

En wikipedia aparecen unos cuantos en la entrada del [Pangrama](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pangrama)

> José compró una vieja zampoña en Perú. Excusándose, Sofía tiró su whisky al desagüe de la banqueta.
>
> El cadáver de Wamba, rey godo de España, fue exhumado y trasladado en una caja de zinc que pesó un kilo.
>
> El veloz murciélago hindú comía feliz cardillo y kiwi. La cigüeña tocaba el saxofón detrás del palenque de paja (Para las fuentes de Microsoft).
>
> El viejo Señor Gómez pedía queso, kiwi y habas, pero le ha tocado un saxofón.
>
> Jovencillo emponzoñado de whisky: ¡qué figurota exhibe! (para la fuentes tipográficas bajo las distribuciones GNU/Linux).
>
> Whisky bueno: ¡excitad mi frágil pequeña vejez!
>
> Quiere la boca exhausta vid, kiwi, piña y fugaz jamón.
>
> Cien kilogramos pesó el extranjero, que vive y se exhibe fumando.
>
> El pingüino Wenceslao hizo kilómetros bajo exhaustiva lluvia y frío, añoraba a su querido cachorro.

Con especial énfasis en los siguientes, que denomina "perfectos" por  usar todas las letras del idioma, con y sin marcas diacríticas.

> (De una sola narración) Benjamín pidió una bebida de kiwi y fresa. Noé, sin vergüenza, la más exquisita champaña del menú.
>
> (De una sola narración) Jovencillo emponzoñado de whisky, ¡qué figurota exhibe!
>
> (De dos narraciones) José compró en Perú una vieja zampoña. Excusándose, Sofía tiró su whisky al desagüe de la banqueta.
>
> (De dos narraciones) El veloz murciélago hindú comía feliz cardillo y kiwi. La cigüeña tocaba el saxofón detrás del palenque de paja.

Algunos otros de [esta web](https://www.somoswaka.com/blog/2016/09/pangrama-visualizar-tipografias/):

> Le gustaba cenar un exquisito sándwich de jamón con zumo de piña y vodka frío.
>
> Es extraño mojar queso en la cerveza y probar whisky de garrafa.
>
> Bebo whisky porque extraño mi loca juventud fugaz.